# Find and replace string with line breaks using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-replace

Have several instances of html code like that in a file, and would like to get rid of one out of these three break lines using Notepad++ in each instance found.

```
...</span></span></span><br />
<br />
<br />
```

What am I doing wrong here?
[image]

Comment: Try `\r?\n<br />\r?\n<br />` or `\R<br />\R<br />`

Comment: The fourth bird's solution with (*) Regular expression. If you see on the status line at the right "Windows (CRLF)" you'll need `\r\n`

Comment: You can use `\R` to mean any line-break.

Answer (score 1):

Used The fourth bird's and Joop Eggen's solution in extended search mode and it worked nicely for me.

Find what `\r\n<br />\r\n<br />`
Replace with `\r\n<br />`